# Jenkinsfile with user input with variable in choices

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use new Jenkinsfile for new job.

I have jenkinsfile which I have in a solo repository:

1. I get branches from another GitLab repository by `git ls-remote` in bash. And I store them in variables: branch1, branch2, branch3....
2. Then I want to use these variables in user input choices

   ```
    script {                
      env.BRANCHDEPLOY = input message: 'User input required',
      ok: 'Deploy!',
      parameters: [choice(name: 'Branch to deploy', choices: '${branch1}\n${branch2}\n${branch3}', description: 'What branch you wont deploy?')]
    }
    echo "${env.BRANCHDEPLOY}"
   ```
3. Then I will use `${env.BRANCHDEPLOY}` for git to deploy selected branch.

Problem is that I can't get to work it with variables in user choice.

I just need to let the user choose the branch that they want deployed from another GitLab repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just making the mistake of doing single quotes around your variables which have to be replaced by the script, So just change the single quotes around to double quotes and it works.

```
"${branch1}\n${branch2}\n${branch3}"
```

Example: Stage two prints the selected choice

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment{
    branch1 = 'stack'
    branch2 = 'over'
    branch3 = 'flow'
}

stages {
    stage('Stage-One') {
        steps {
            script {                
                env.BRANCHDEPLOY = input message: 'User input required',
                ok: 'Deploy!',
                parameters: [choice(name: 'Branch to deploy', choices: "${branch1}\n${branch2}\n${branch3}", description: 'What branch you wont deploy?')]
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Stage-Two'){
        steps{
            sh "echo ${BRANCHDEPLOY}"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Chandan Nayak, but I get an error with double quotes. "No such property: branch1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Comment: Please use one hardcoded environment to test it first, For example, make sure you can print sh "echo ${env.branch1}"

Comment: With: environment{branch1 = 'stack'} I get result "stack" from sh "echo ${env.branch1}". but in input it not work.

Comment: Yes withEnv = environment {}, please check with my snippet it works.

Comment: please use `BRANCHDEPLOY = input message:` instead of `env.BRANCHDEPLOY = input message:` as if multiple parameters env would force map result to string

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that, you should be able to pass tha var.

```
parameters {
    string(branchName: 'feature_x')
}
scm {
    checkout(
      branches: [[name: '*/$branchName']], 
....

 }
```